# What does "The last merge operation tried to add the file 'x.cs' but the file was obstructed in the working copy." mean?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN to do a merge. I'm trying to merge /branch/A into /branch/B which were both branched from /trunk. I'm getting a Tree Conflict and the dialog contains a message like this:

> The last merge operation tried to add the file 'x.cs' but the file was
>   obstructed in the working copy.

It gives me the option to Accept the current working copy, postpone or resolve later.

I thought this meant that two files of the same name had been added separately to each branch. Have I understood what this conflict is correctly? If I have, why is it not giving me the option to Merge the two files together?

Answer (score 20):

It means that a file named `x.cs` was added in `branch/B`. However, in `branch/A` there was also a file named `x.cs` added. Both files named `x.cs` are not related but were added independently.

Now you're trying to merge `branch/A` into `branch/B`. That merge tries to add the file `x.cs` that was added in `branch/A` now to `branch/B`. But there already is a file named `x.cs` in `branch/B`, and that file obstructs the one from `branch/A`.

That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: It seems that when merging just a single file from another branch, the path to that file must be given in the TortoiseSVN merge dialog 'URL to merge from'.

Comment: The latter comment from @Cameron is the answer.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue.  Knowing what the issue is, how do we proceed?  What are the recommended easy way of at least having the option to diff both files to do a manual merge?

Comment: @mgouin It's probably not the 'right' way, but in situations like this, I generally pick a version to commit, make sure all the relevant changes are in that file, mark that conflict as resolved, and commit from there.